# could you show me latest executable flutter FCM push notification example code in android?

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, badge

I'm newbie in flutter, in progress using badge notification to my app, I got trouble.

Anything else in web example I tried but it's not worked to me.

Could you show me basic snippet to understand flutter badge notification android version?

Not only badge notification, but basic push notification example also would help to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone else like me check this tutorial, Official site example.

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview

And, push notification basically includes badge notification.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).